# I want more time with my wife in our blended family, but she says no.

Tags: communication, step-parents, fighting, time-management

My wife and I have been married for about 8 months. We both have two children, each. I moved into her house with her kids. I have my kids twice a week and every other weekend.

I told my wife I wanted to spend time with her during the week after her kids went to bed. She refuses.

In fact, we've gotten into a very heated argument. She won't listen to my reasoning and she claims I'm not listening to her. I disagree and think I am listening. Am I being unreasonable?

She thinks I'm trying to take time away from her kids. I have kept on telling her that it's only after her kids go to bed. I don't know what to do.

I'm fed up with lacking time together with her both during the week and during the weekends we have our kids. The only time we spend together without our kids directly involved (not asleep) is every other weekend when our kids are with each other's ex.

What can I do? Am I wrong?

Comment: Hi, Jon, and welcome to the site. I'm not sure that this is a parenting question, and there's a lot that you haven't told us. Was this a problem before your marriage? If not, what's changed? What are her objections? What do you mean by time with her after the kids go to bed (you don't go to separate rooms, I take it.) More info will get you a better answer. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I don't think anyone here can tell you if you're right or not.  I can tell you from long experience that being right is irrelevant in any event.  We can't tell you if you're right or wrong to want more time together, but what perhaps you might get if you want it is suggestions for how to approach this.  You might need to give a bit more details for that - such as how often you are child-free between the two of you, and what kinds of options you have.

Comment: // , Would you be willing to add more facts (as anonymously as possible) and indicate any other research efforts you've made, Jon? 

This sounds like a great item to send in as a letter to a site like wayneandtamara.com, or another advice columnist.

Comment: Jon, can you please edit your question to clarify some points that have been brought up by other users? Getting time away from your kids can be topical for parenting (everyone needs a break), but right now this is more about _relationship communication_ which isn't quite a good fit, and will also lead to a lot of opinion-based answers. All the comments and answers so far indicate the situation is not clear enough for a good answer. Once you edit it, I'll be happy to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what the issue is, whether it's that her kids are sleeping where you two sleep, or that she just goes to bed right away once they're asleep, or something else. Editing your question to make that clearer would help.

However, I recommend you stop trying to get her to agree to something in general (especially after she has refused) and instead try for specifics. So if she's just going to bed right away when they do, and you would rather watch some recorded TV with her, or sit down and plan a vacation together, or whatever, you could ask her "can you stay up for an hour and [specific thing] with me tonight? She may say no, she's too tired. She may give it a try. If she gives it a try and you both enjoy it, you can point out that it was enjoyable. Then the next night (or whenever) suggest it again. If she's too tired, then the next day in plenty of time before the kids go to bed, you can ask what you can do to help her be able to stay up later and do things together.

This may require some big changes for you. Is she getting up at 5 and doing things before the kids wake up? If you got up early too would those chores go faster? Is she cooking, cleaning, and generally exhausting herself in the early evening? Can some of that be left to the weekend, or can you do some of it? You need to understand what the issues are and how you can help, instead of being another chore on a huge to-do list "spend time with whiny husband." I know that would be a sad thought, but sometimes when one spouse is worn out and the other one is "why don't we relax together?" the most helpful thing you can do is roll up your sleeves and pitch in. Not to the point where you're both doing the same amount, but to the point where you're the same tired. That's the only way you'll both stay up the same lateness each night.

Answer (score 2):

// , The first thing you can do is decide your boundaries, that is, what you do and do not see as a violation of trust.

Right or wrong, she is her own person. **So are you, Jon.**

People who take responsibility for themselves decide what sort of relationship *they* want, and act carefully on their decisions.

Decide whether you want it 4 days per week, or per month.

That is my answer.

However, I feel obligated to add the following:

This doesn't sound like the sort of question that a parenting forum like this can handle precisely. The children are just part, here, of a larger situation.

Two sentences stand out to me:

"I moved into her house with her kids."

and

"The only time we can spend together w/o our kids is every other weekend when our kids are with each other's ex."

You both live there. Except for 4 days per week, you do not spend exclusive time together, even at night, even with sleeping kids. Something's missing from that story.

My experience of family comes mostly from the Midwest, and stolid, stable middle-class families integrated into a closely-knit extended family. I have made myself a scholar of the best relationships I can make available to my eyes.

That said, though my experience is limited, parting when there is no pressing business not only seems odd, but very strange. Her side of the story is missing.

Do you have separate rooms? Is this some sort of huge house? Does "spending time while the kids are asleep" entail some sort of special activity aside from literally just being in each others presence? I mean, does she lock herself in a closet, or something? Do you have separate beds?

I think there is a lot more to this story than would allow anything more than a suggestion for further research.

Comment: Sometimes people need to hear things a certain way, so approaching the problem differently and communicating in a different way may also help.